# Data structure for a basic circuit

Tags: python, data-structures, graph

To create a very, very basic circuit simulator that accepts the following components:

- DC Battery source with a fixed, non-changing voltage
- Wire connections with zero resistance
- Resistors with a fixed resistance

I would like to 'describe' a setup such as:

[image]

I suppose the 'components' could look like this:

```
class Battery:
    def __init__(self, voltage=None):
        self.voltage = voltage

class Resistor:
    def __init__(self, resistance=None):
        self.resistance = resistance

class Wire:
    # how to describe variable connections?


>>> V = Battery(9)
>>> R1, R2, R3 = Resistor(10e3), Resistor(2e3), Resistor(1e3)
```

And then once I have the components, what would be an example of how to describe how all of them would be 'connected'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `start` and `end` parameters that indicate where in the circuit the components are.

```py
class BaseComponent:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<{self.__class__.__name__} start={self.start} end={self.end} at 0x{id(self):x}>'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not type(self)==type(other):
            return False
        return all(v==getattr(other, k) for k, v in self.__dict__.items())

class Battery(BaseComponent):
    def __init__(self, start, end, voltage=None):
        super().__init__(start, end)
        self.voltage = voltage

class Resistor(BaseComponent):
    def __init__(self, start, end, resistance=None):
        super().__init__(start, end)
        self.resistance = resistance

class Wire(BaseComponent):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        super().__init__(start, end)
```

Then you can make a layout via:

```py
V = Battery(8, 1, voltage=9)
w1, w2, w3 = Wire(1, 2), Wire(2, 3), Wire(3, 4)
R1, R2, R3 = Resistor(2, 7, 10e3), Resistor(3, 6, 2e3), Resistor(4, 5, 1e3)
w5, w6, w7 = Wire(5, 6), Wire(6, 7), Wire(7, 8)
```

If you want to get fancy, you can turn it into a graph as well.

```py
class Circuit:
    """A directed graph structure for building circuits"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Creates the graph.  Note only one edge is allowed between nodes"""
        self._outward = {}
        self._inward = {}

    @staticmethod
    def _norm(name):
        return str(name)

    def add_node(self, name):
        """
        Adds a single node to the graph. The `name` is converted to a string.
        """
        node = self._norm(name)
        # check for existance
        if node in self._outward:
            return node
        self._outward.setdefault(node, {})
        self._inward.setdefault(node, {})
        return node

    def add_component(self, component):
        """
        Adds a circuitry component to the circuit.
        """
        s = self._norm(component.start)
        e = self._norm(component.end)
        if self.has_edge(s, e):
            raise KeyError(f'A link from {s} to {e} already exists')
        start = self.add_node(component.start)
        end = self.add_node(component.end)
        self._outward[start][end] = component
        self._inward[end][start] = component

    def has_node(self, node):
        return self._norm(node) in self._outward

    def has_component(self, component):
        start = self._norm(component.start)
        end = self._norm(component.end)
        return component==self._outward.get(start, {}).get(end)

    def has_edge(self, start, end):
        s = self._norm(start)
        e = self._norm(end)
        return bool(e in self._outward.get(s, {}))

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.add_component(other)
        return self
```

From here you can build the circuit via:

```py
circuit = Circuit()
for c in (V, w1, w2, w3, R1, R2, R3, w5, w6, w7):
    circuit.add_component(c)
```

Comment: Great job with this! The effort definitely shows :)

Comment: This was a very fun little coding project.